# Decomposing a given $2\times2$ matrix as a product of two non-identity matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X = \left( \begin{matrix} -8 & 7 \\ 2 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $. Give an example of two $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$, neither of which is the identity matrix $I$, such that $AB = X$.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't elementary row operations be represented as matrix multiplication?

Comment: Well, you could use $-I$...

Comment: How can I use them? Could you show me please? Thanks.

Comment: You can use any of the methods that are used in numerical linear algebra. LU decomposition, QR decomposition and so on.

Comment: @orion thanks :)

Comment: Pick $A$. Now you have a problem "Find a matrix $B$ such that $AB = X$". This is one of those problems that really highlights that *simply trying things* rather than staring at the problem trying to "think" your way to the answer is important -- you have so much freedom in this problem, there are a tremendous number of things you might do that will move you to a place where you have a problem you know how to solve, and not many things that are so wrong you can't push them through to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

write the coefficients of the matrices A and B as a,b,c,...,h. Then write the equations for matrix multiplication, solve them and make sure you don't end up with an identity matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Take any nonsingular $2\times2$  matrix $A$, and finid its inverse $A^{-1}$.

Now define $B$ as the product $A^{-1}X$.  Now multiply $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Please tell us more about what you have tried and where you are stuck. I will give you some hints to get started. I assume the entries don't have to be integers. For matrices

$$A = \left( \begin{matrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4 \end{matrix} \right) $$

$$B = \left( \begin{matrix} b_1 & b_2 \\ b_3 & b_4 \end{matrix} \right) $$

By the properties of matrix multiplication, we now know that

$$a_1 \cdot b_1 + a_2 \cdot b_3 = -8$$
$$a_1 \cdot b_2 + a_2 \cdot b_4 = 7$$
$$a_3 \cdot b_1 + a_4 \cdot b_3 = 2$$
$$a_3 \cdot b_2 + a_4 \cdot b_4 = 0$$

By choosing some values for $a_1, \dots a_4$ so that $A$ still is invertible (for example $a_i = i$), we can find fitting values of $b_1, \dots, b_4$ by solving the above system of (linear) equations. Let us know if you need more assistance.

Comment: I chose these values for example,

a1 = 4  a2 = 1
a3 = -1  a4 = 0

b1= -2    b2= 0
b3= 1     b4= 3


But when you use these values the result is not equal to X

Comment: That is not a solution. Do you know how to solve systems of linear equations?

Comment: Yes I do. But I couldn't solve this one,interestingly.

Comment: @naslundx The equations aren't linear unless either $A$ or $B$ is given.

Comment: @Daryl As I wrote, if we pick some values for $A$, the equations are linear in terms of elements of $B$. We only need to make sure $A$ is still invertible (I will add that).

Comment: There are 8 unknowns here, so how can I solve them isn't it a bit difficult. I mean should I made up the unknowns?

Comment: @oguzhandalgic choose some values for the matrix A sucht that A is invertible and then solve the linear system that naslundx gave to you ;) everything should be fine. If it's not then you made a mistake.

Comment: @naslundx I missed that phrase in your answer...

Comment: @oguzhandalgic Yes, for any (invertible), matrix A you can find a B that fits AB=X. Try $a_1=1, a_2=2, a_3=3, a_4=4$, that works.

Comment: @naslundx thanks I solved it :)

Comment: @oguzhandalgic Very good! :)

Answer (score 0):

By using LU decomposition the answer can be found as

> **A** = \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1/4 & 1 \end{matrix}
>
> **B** = \begin{matrix} -8 & 7 \\ 0 & 7/4 \end{matrix}